# How to toggle two elements correctly with two buttons?

Tags: javascript

I want to show cards when cards is clicked and show table when table is clicked. But by default, one of them needs to show at the beginning with the other hidden. But if either button is clicked on again the div will stay to what is clicked on.
I have it half way working. If you start on the table button first you will see it working until you click again (same button) or start on the cards button. Any help is appreciated.
[Here](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/6228155?key=361f50d2862772ae2df1d8ab314e61ec) is an example of what I need.

```js
const targetTable = document.getElementById("table");
const targetCards = document.getElementById("cards");
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("toggle2");


targetCards.style.display = "block";
targetTable.style.display = "none";

btn.onclick = function () {
  if (targetTable.style.display !== "none") {
    targetTable.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    targetTable.style.display = "block";
    targetCards.style.display = "none";
  }
};

btn2.onclick = function () {
  if (targetCards.style.display !== "none") {
    targetCards.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    targetCards.style.display = "block";
    targetTable.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cards">This div shows cards.</div>
  <div id="table">This div shows table.</div>
  <button id="toggle">table</button>
  <button id="toggle2">cards</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to approach it. Use classes to consolidate your functions, then use a data-attribute to designate which button reveals what item

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.toggler').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let targ = `#${e.target.dataset.ref}`;
    // set them all to hidden
    document.querySelectorAll('.toggles').forEach(div => div.classList.add('hide'));
    // reveal the one we want
    document.querySelector(targ).classList.remove('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards" class='toggles'>This div shows cards.</div>
<div id="table" class='toggles hide'>This div shows table.</div>
<button class='toggler' data-ref='table'>table</button>
<button class='toggler' data-ref='cards'>cards</button>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but this is not what I am looking for. The buttons need to toggle. If table button is clicked then cards div is removed and table div shows. Then the opposite with the cards button should happen. Only one div should always be showing. I have it half way working in my code above. I need to be able to do it with elements the way the code is setup with another library...

Comment: I understand - see my revised answer

Comment: That is almost what I need but with two buttons. I updated my post above and put a video link to show further the output needed. Sorry I have not explained it correctly. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Ok, third time's a charm? Updated answer

Comment: Thank you your royalty :)

Answer (score 2):

Little late, but i like js tasks :-)

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
const elem = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');

btns.forEach((b) => {  
  b.addEventListener('click', (e) => {    
    const t = e.target.getAttribute('data-type');    
    const classList = document.getElementById(t).classList;
    if (classList.length > 1) {
      elem.forEach((c) => {            
        c.classList.toggle('hidden')
      })      
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="cards" class="elem ">This div shows cards.</div>
  <div id="table" class="elem hidden">This div shows table.</div>

  
  <button class="toggle" data-type="table">table</button>
  <button class="toggle" data-type="cards">cards</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Maik for your help.

Comment: @StephenW Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you've overcomplicated it with the if statements. There's need to check what the current states are, you can just set them to what the buttons are supposed to do.

The functions can look like this:

```
btn.onclick = function () {
  targetCards.style.display = "none";
  targetTable.style.display = "block";
};

btn2.onclick = function () {
  targetTable.style.display = "none";
  targetCards.style.display = "block";
};
```

And here's the whole working snippet:

```js
const targetTable = document.getElementById("table");
const targetCards = document.getElementById("cards");
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("toggle2");


targetCards.style.display = "block";
targetTable.style.display = "none";

btn.onclick = function () {
  targetCards.style.display = "none";
  targetTable.style.display = "block";
};

btn2.onclick = function () {
  targetTable.style.display = "none";
  targetCards.style.display = "block";
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cards">This div shows cards.</div>
  <div id="table">This div shows table.</div>
  <button id="toggle">table</button>
  <button id="toggle2">cards</button>
</body>
```

You could also get a little bit fancy by having one button that toggles the display. It's not much more complicated.

```js
const targetTable = document.getElementById("table");
const targetCards = document.getElementById("cards");
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");

targetCards.style.display = "block";
targetTable.style.display = "none";

btn.onclick = function () {
  if (targetTable.style.display !== "none") {
    targetTable.style.display = "none";
    targetCards.style.display = "block";
    btn.innerHTML = "table";
  } else {
    targetTable.style.display = "block";
    targetCards.style.display = "none";
    btn.innerHTML = "cards";
  }
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cards">This div shows cards.</div>
  <div id="table">This div shows table.</div>
  <button id="toggle">table</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see your example (I don't know why). But, if I correctly understood your question (please, let me know), this is what you want to achieve:

```js
table.style.display = "none";

toggle.onclick = () => {
  cards.style.display = "none";
  table.style.display = "block";
}

toggle2.onclick = () => {
  cards.style.display = "block";
  table.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">This div shows cards.</div>
<div id="table">This div shows table.</div>
<button id="toggle">table</button>
<button id="toggle2">cards</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. You understood it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `classList.toggle` and `dataset`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button) =>
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach((content) => {
      content.classList.toggle("hide", content.id !== event.target.dataset.id);
    });
  })
);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div id="cards" class='content'>This div shows cards.</div>
<div id="table" class='content hide'>This div shows table.</div>
<button data-id='table'>table</button>
<button data-id='cards'>cards</button>
```